# I can't print out results from Math class in long data type in Java?

Tags: java, exception, long-integer

I'm trying to create a table with n from 16 to 2048 along with log(n), n*log(n)...

At first, I printf-ed the results in double and it worked out just fine except for the fact that the table was not aligned but rather messed up at n = 256. I figure that the results might have been too big for the double data type so I switched to long.

```
public class FunctionGrowth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long n = 16L;
        System.out.println("log(n) \tn \t\tn*log(n)\t\tn^2 \tn^3 \t\t2^n");

        while(n <= 2048) {
            long l = (long) Math.log(n);
            long nl = (long) (n*Math.log(n));
            long pow = (long) Math.pow(n,2);
            long cube = (long) Math.pow(n,3);
            long pow2 =(long) Math.pow(2,n);

            System.out.printf("%.2d\t%.0d\t\t%.2d\t\t\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\n", l, n, nl, pow, cube, pow2);
            n = n*2;
        }
    }
}
```

Yet now I have a new problem: 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2

I have tried many ways to cast log(n), pow(n,2)... from Math class to long, but nothing works so far.

Could you help me with this problem? I'm struggling a lot.

Comment: As far a I know you specify precision for floating point values, not for longs. Use `System.out.printf("%d\t%d\t\t%d\t\t\t%d\t%d\t\t%d\n", l, n, nl, pow, cube, pow2);`

Comment: Thank you it worked but the table is still messed up :(

Comment: First of all, how many bits does a long have? Given that number of bits, what is the largest number it can hold? (Hint: to know that, find the largest number you can hold in 1 bit, then 2 bits, then 3 bits, etc.) What do you conclude regarding your code? Second, where is the exception thrown? Read its stack trace to find out. It doesn't have anything with the values. It has everything to do with the format you trying to use: `%.2d`.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you experienced is due to specifying precision for integral types, which is not valid.

This behavior is specified in the `Formatter` class Javadoc:

> Precision
>
> For general argument types, the precision is the maximum number of characters to be written to the output.
>
> For the floating-point conversions 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', and 'f' the precision is the number of digits after the radix point. If the conversion is 'g' or 'G', then the precision is the total number of digits in the resulting magnitude after rounding.
>
> For character, **integral**, and date/time argument types and the percent and line separator conversions, **the precision is not applicable; if a precision is provided, an exception will be thrown**.

Answer (score 0):

The Error that you are getting is because you are formatting long values to int values and int does not support precision formatting. Try casting your long values to floats and changing the format specifier (%.2d and similar ones) to float specifiers (%.2f and similar).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use DecimalFormat:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long n = 16L;
    System.out.println("log(n) \tn \t\tn*log(n)\t\tn^2 \tn^3 \t\t2^n");

    while(n <= 2048) {
        long l = (long) Math.log(n);
        long nl = (long) (n*Math.log(n));
        long pow = (long) Math.pow(n,2);
        long cube = (long) Math.pow(n,3);
        long pow2 =(long) Math.pow(2,n);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        String format = df.format(l) + "\t" +  df.format((nl)) + "\t" + df.format(pow) + "\t" + df.format(cube) + "\t" + df.format(pow2);
        System.out.println(format);
        n = n*2;
    }
}
```

You have more information about DecimalFormat here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended but you can hack a way like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long n = 16L;

    // Do use format number accordingly
    int format = 20;

    System.out.printf(
        "%" + format + "s\t" +
            "%" + format + "s\t" +
            "%" + format + "s\t" +
            "%" + format + "s\t"+
            "%" + format + "s\t" +
            "%" + format + "s\n", "log(n)", "(n)", "nlog(n)", "n^2", "n^3", "2^n");

    //System.out.println("log(n) \tn \t\tn*log(n)\t\tn^2 \tn^3 \t\t2^n");

    while (n <= 2048) {
        long l = (long) Math.log(n);
        long nl = (long) (n * Math.log(n));
        long pow = (long) Math.pow(n, 2);
        long cube = (long) Math.pow(n, 3);
        long pow2 = (long) Math.pow(2, n);

        System.out.printf(
            "%" + format + "d\t" +
            "%" + format + "d\t" +
            "%" + format + "d\t" +
            "%" + format + "d\t"+
            "%" + format + "d\t" +
            "%" + format + "d\n", l, n, nl, pow, cube, pow2);
        n = n * 2;
    }
}
```

[image: OutPut for the above snippet]